# Lagrange Multiplier problem - Find the dimensions for maximum valume

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

> Find the dimensions for the maximum volume of a cuboid under this
>   slightly strange condition.
>
> It has its total length of edges equal to the square of the space
>   diagonal length.

I am having trouble with this question as I can't seem to get anywhere with the x, y and z dimensions. So far I have said that:

x is the width of the box

y is the depth of the box

z is the height of the box

the square of the space diagonal $d^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2$

the perimeter would be $4x+4y+4z$

Volume of cuboid is $xyz$

Using the lagrange multiplier formula $$L=xyz-\lambda(x^2+y^2+z^2-4x-4y-4z)$$
$$L_x = yz-\lambda(2x-4) =0 \Rightarrow \lambda = \frac {yz}{2x-4}$$
$$L_y = xz-\lambda(2y-4) =0 \Rightarrow \lambda = \frac {xz}{2y-4}$$
$$L_y = xy-\lambda(2z-4) =0 \Rightarrow \lambda = \frac {xy}{2z-4}$$

The problem I'm having is when I make the $\lambda$ equal to each other, I can't seem to find the dimensions. Any advice or hints would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: $\lambda = \frac {yz}{2x-4} = \frac {xz}{2y-4}$  You can safely assume that $x,y,z >0$ or the volume would be 0 and not maximized.  Work that out and you should get that $x=y$

Answer (score 0):

no the mistake you have done is using $\lambda$ alone.Use two parameters.Say $xyz-\lambda_1(x^2+y^2+z^2)-\lambda_2(4x+4y+4z)=0$.